# Protractor Map or Filter function on a table which is having repeater with inside div elements

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, css-tables, gulp-protractor

Below is the html for a table with repeater> div> a> span.

How I can work with filter or Map function to get the compare the second column value i.e idea = ideaOne + ideaTwo + ideaThree + ideaFour along with first column value in loop as this is an anchor tag. Also what would be the proper way to deal with all table values.

Repeater gives me the complete table values but when we use filter & try to click on the first cell value, it's did perform any action neither fail the It block. console value shows all the repeater values are coming in array.

Page Object Class-

```
getAllTableValues: function () {
    return element.all(by.repeater('idea in ctrl.ideaList.ideas')).filter(function(elem) {
      return elem.getText().then(function(text) {
        return text === 'K';
      });
    }).click();
  },
```

Spec Class:

```
 tablePage.getAllTableValues().then(function (val) {
  console.log("@@@@"+ val);
});
```

Html Code:

```
<ul class="total_ideas">
                    <!----><li ng-repeat="idea in ctrl.ideaList.ideas" class="" style="">

                        <div class="protractor testing">
                            <a class="item_idea" ui-sref="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx({
                                    'id': idea.id,
                                    'value': idea.name,
                                    'start': (ctrl.dateRange.start | date: 'M-d-y'),
                                    'end': (ctrl.dateRange.end | date: 'M-d-y')
                            })" href="/xxx/xxx/;value=K">
                                K
                            </a>
                        </div>

                        <div class="protractor test testing">
                            <span ng-bind="ctrl.getTotalIdeas(idea)">6</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="protractor test testing">
                            <span ng-bind="idea.testTerms[ctrl.period].ideaOne">2</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="protractor test testing">
                            <span ng-bind="idea.testTerms[ctrl.period].ideaTwo">2</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="protractor test testing">
                            <span ng-bind="idea.testTerms[ctrl.period].ideaThree">2</span>
                        </div>

                        <div class="protractor test testing">
                            <span ng-bind="idea.testTerms[ctrl.period].ideaFour">0</span>
                        </div>

                    </li><!----><li ng-repeat="idea in ctrl.ideaList.ideas" class="">

                    </li><!---->
                </ul>
```

Please suggest here.